# Setting package option from the command line

Tags: compiling, optional-arguments, tcolorbox

I want to compile a document that uses the [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox) package in two different ways:

- with the option `/tcb/lowerbox` set to `visible`, so that the lower part of the `tcolorbox` environment is typeset
- with the option `/tcb/lowerbox` set to `ignored`, so that the lower part of the `tcolorbox` environment is not used.

At the beginning of the document there is the command

```
\tcbset{lowerbox=ignored}
```

which should be commented for the first case only.

Is it possible to control this behaviour from the command line when compiling the document, so that I do not have to edit the source explicitly in order to have the two versions of the document?

Here is a minimal working example. Let's say it is saved as `test.tex`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

%\tcbset{lowerbox=ignored}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
  Upper part.
  \tcblower
  Lower part.
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `pdflatex '\AtBeginDocument{\tcbset{lowerbox=visible}}\input{file}'` might do. Can you add a short example to play with?

Comment: @egreg Your suggestion works. Are you going to turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add code to be executed when LaTeX scans `\begin{document}`. So long as `\tcbset{lowerbox=ignored}` is executed before `\begin{document}`, calling

```
pdflatex '\AtBeginDocument{\tcbset{lowerbox=visible}}\input{<filename>}'
```

for processing `<filename>.tex` should do. Read on if it doesn't.

---

Not every setting can be passed this way; for instance, if package `foo.sty` sets its options at `\begin{document}`, say calling `\fooset{baz=true}`, adding

```
\AtBeginDocument{\fooset{baz=false}}
```

to the command line would do nothing, because the order in which the calls are executed would be

```
\AtBeginDocument{\fooset{baz=false}}
...
\usepackage{foo}
```

which becomes

```
\fooset{baz=false}% <-- from the command line
\fooset{baz=true}% <-- from \usepackage{foo}
```

A way out is adding a layer, using `\AtEndPreamble` (requires `\usepackage{etoolbox}` in the document):

```
pdflatex '\AtEndPreamble{\AtBeginDocument{\fooset{baz=false}}}\input{<filename>}'
```

Comment: Usually I compile my documents with [`latexmk`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/latexmk) with the command `latexmk -pvc -pdf <filename>`. How can the method described in the answer be adapted to be used with `latexmk`, if possible at all?

Comment: The last command given in this answer does not work because of the requirement on the `etoolbox` package. How can this requirement be inserted in the given command?

Comment: You can add `\RequirePackage{etoolbox}` before `\AtEndPreamble`; for `latexmk` you have to use the `-pdflatex="..."` option, check the doc.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This is the full command I used with Miktex 2.9 on Windows OS: `pdflatex --job-name=My_LaTeX_Filename_ArXiV "\RequirePackage{etoolbox}\AtEndPreamble{\AtBeginDocument{\pagestyle{fancy}}}\input{My_LaTeX_Filename}" `

Answer (score 6):

You can avoid the `\AtBeginDocument` problems with this approach:

```
\ifdefined\ignorelowerbox\tcbset{lowerbox=ignored}\fi
```

in the preamble. Then

```
pdflatex '\def\ignorelowerbox{true}\input{<filename>}'
```

if you want to ignore and

```
pdflatex '\input{<filename>}'
```

if not. This method is completely general (uses the `e-TeX` `ifdefined` for conciseness).

One could devise other schemes in this style unfortunately LaTeX has put the `@` in quite a few useful things like `\@namedef` or `\@firstoftwo` hence this is more complicated as one would have to set the catcode etc... to use them.

Comment: and `\csname ... \endcsname` is too long to type in the command line.